# Angular application showing blank screen

Tags: angular, console, runtime-error

I am very new to angular development. I got this angular app code base from my team and attempting to run it locally. I installed node js, npm amd angular cli. I got lot of issues while trying to execute ng serve. But I finally got ride of those.
Now the problem is the app compiles successfully using ng serve. But when I navigate to the url(http://localhost:4200) I am seeing a blank screen. I am supposed to get a login page. To troubleshoot, I hit F12 in chrome and able to see the console error shown below:

[image: Console error in browser]

Please find the software versions below:
[image: Version info]

Any help to enable me see the login page can definitely help

Comment: can you put your appmodule.ts codes please ?

Comment: @pc_coder Hello Sir. There is a problem with node_modules version that I was using. I reverted it back to the one that was used for developing this code and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular application's bootstraping starts from main.ts file. Open main.ts file and check which module's name is used in bootStrapModule.
Once done please check the parent module for any errors in the import statements.

Comment: I think there is a problem with node_modules that I am using. This code base was given to me by a team. And when I tried to install angular 6.x version on my own I got this issue. But I got rid of my node modules and used the one that the other team had given me. And then it worked. Need to check why the latest version gave me this issue. Its however hard to interpret what went wrong with the console error message and with no compilation issues.

Comment: Hello Anamika Dadhich. The version of node_modules components that I was using was different than the one which the development team was using. I switched back to their version and then the app was working fine. Thanks for the suggestion though